# How do I play Minecraft maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There's a map, how do I use those maps to create singleplayer world? Please tell me, there is a map called oneblock skyblock, how do I use it to create a world to play on?

Comment: [Google for `minecraft import map`](https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft+import+map) and there are plenty of results.

Comment: Most of the results (for me) only work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

**How to Download and Use Minecraft Maps:**

First, download the map you would like to use. The file downloaded is usually a zip folder, so extract it by pressing `extract all`.

After downloading the map, you now must put it into your Minecraft `saves` folder. This is the folder in Minecraft that stores all of your worlds.

But, when you look through your file explorer, you will notice you cannot find the `.minecraft` folder anywhere! To get to your Minecraft folder, do `windows+r` and in the text prompt, type in `%appdata%` and press `ok`.

This will open a file explorer window with all of the files of your programs. Try to find a folder called `.minecraft` and open it. Scroll down to the bottom and find a folder called `saves` and open it. Now open another file explorer window, and drag the map folder into the `saves` folder. And congratulations! Your map is now in Minecraft! Relaunch the game and you should see your map in your worlds.

---